# How do you unsubscribe Firebase ChildAdded events in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple posts, each with their own comments. So when I open a comment list for a post, I want to start listening for `ChildAdded` events to load the comments.
I have

```
public void StartListening(string postKey) {  
  databaseReference
    .Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts)
    .Child(postKey)
    .Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments))
    .ChildAdded += OnCommentChildAdded;
}
```

This will get all the current comments and then if anyone comments live in real-time (including the current user) it will show up in the list as well.

When I close that post and go to a different post, I want to STOP listening for comments on the old post and start listening on another post. So I have

```
databaseReference 
 .Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts) 
 .Child(postKey)
 .Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments))
 .ChildAdded -= OnCommentChildAdded;
```

to stop listening to the original **postKey**, then I call the first function again with a new **postKey**.

My issue is that when I go BACK to the original post and call `StartListening(originalPostKey);` it loads all the existing children fine, but when I add a comment in real-time it triggers `OnCommentChildAdded` twice, as if the first subscription event was never unsubscribed.

Does anyone know how the Firebase Child Events in Unity C# work, and how can I get this to work without hacks (e.g checking a set to see if the **postKey** was already added).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell without seeing the code of where, how and when you actually execute your snippets.

However, in general try to always do `-=` before using `+=`. This is also valid if the listener was never attached yet but should make sure it is only added **exactly once** even if `StartListening` is called multiple times.

```
public void StartListening(string postKey) 
{  
    var child = databaseReference.Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts).Child(postKey).Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments));

    child.ChildAdded -= OnCommentChildAdded; 
    child.ChildAdded += OnCommentChildAdded; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is because you are removing the listener on the wrong post. If your code looks like this block, you remove the listener on the new post, not the old one. However, this doesn't explain why the listener would be added twice.

```cs
StartListening(string postKey) {  
  databaseReference.Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts).Child(postKey).Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments)).ChildAdded -= OnCommentChildAdded;
  databaseReference.Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts).Child(postKey).Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments)).ChildAdded += OnCommentChildAdded;
}
```

As an attempt to fix this, you would have to store the key (or the reference) of the post you were listening to previously.

```cs
private string mActivePostKey = null;

public void ListenTo(string postKey) 
{
    // Ignore relistening to the same post (optional)
    if (String.Equals(postKey, mActivePostKey)) return;
    
    // Clear the previous listener, if attached
    if (activePostKey != null) {
      Debug.Log("Detaching listener to " + mActivePostKey);
      var activeChildRef = databaseReference.Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts).Child(mActivePostKey).Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments));
      activeChildRef -= OnCommentChildAdded;
    }
    
    // Add listener
    Debug.Log("Attaching listener to " + postKey);
    var childRef = databaseReference.Child(FirebaseConstants.DatabasePosts).Child(postKey).Child(nameof(PostInfo.Comments));
    childRef.ChildAdded += OnCommentChildAdded; 
    
    // Replace active post key
    mActivePostKey = postKey;
}
```

If the above code functions correctly, the code

```cs
someObject.ListenTo("POST_ID_1")
someObject.ListenTo("POST_ID_2")
someObject.ListenTo("POST_ID_1")
```

should output:

```
Attaching listener to POST_ID_1
Detaching listener to POST_ID_1
Attaching listener to POST_ID_2
Detaching listener to POST_ID_2
Attaching listener to POST_ID_1
```

If the object/class that contains this method is a different instance to the original, then using `-= OnCommentChildAdded;` will not work as the methods would have a different address (i.e. `Instance1#OnCommentChildAdded != Instance2#OnCommentChildAdded`). It would also result in the following messages:

```
Attaching listener to POST_ID_1
Attaching listener to POST_ID_2
Attaching listener to POST_ID_1
```