# Unsubscribe from ChildAdded events in Unity C#/Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:**

I am subscribing to a ChildAdded event and unsubscribing to said event upon clicking 1 of 2 buttons. E.g., if I click the "DisableGlobalChat" button, then I'd expect the current listener to be removed. If I click the "EnableGlobalChat" button, then I'd expect a new listener to be added. The problem is that when disabling and then re-enabling, duplicate listeners are being added, or else the previous listener is not being deactivated.

**Goal:**

Prevent duplicate listeners being added when disabling and then re-enabling the listener.

**Question:**

My code is shown below with comments throughout. Is there an issue in this code that would cause duplicate listeners?

**Code/Background:**

Relevant guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data.
Similar post: [How do you unsubscribe Firebase ChildAdded events in Unity C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128359/how-do-you-unsubscribe-firebase-childadded-events-in-unity-c).

```
public void CurrentListener2(object o2, ChildChangedEventArgs args2) //o2 does not do anything, this is how we instantiate the messages after listening
{

    if (args2.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("there were errors");
    }
    else //upon disabling and enabling the listener, 2 listeners are added. Do it again and the number goes up to 3, etc. This is causing messages to be instantiated multiple times.
    {
        globalJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<GlobalDeserialiseJson>(args2.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
        InstantiateMessageGlobal(globalJson.globalSenderUsername.ToString(), globalJson.globalSenderID.ToString(), globalJson.globalMessageText.ToString());
    }

}

public void GlobalListenForNewMessages() //if global chat is not disabled then add a listener for new childs in the global chat node
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("DisableGlobal") == "F" || PlayerPrefs.HasKey("DisableGlobal") == false)
    {
        //globalListener = CurrentListener2; //trying to set CurrentListener2 to a variable to see if that would change anything, it did not
        globalReference.LimitToLast(1).ChildAdded += CurrentListener2; //looking to the global node, limiting to the most recent message, and adding a listener
        Debug.Log("enabled"); //tracking changes
    }
}
public void GlobalStopListenForNewMessages()///if global chat is disabled then remove the current listener
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("DisableGlobal") == "T")
    {
        globalReference.LimitToLast(1).ChildAdded -= CurrentListener2; //looking to the global node, limiting to the most recent message, and removing a listener
        //globalListener = null; //setting the globalListener to null to see if that would change anything, it did not
        Debug.Log("disabled"); //tracking changes

    }
}
public void DisableGlobalChat() //clicking button to disable global chat
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("DisableGlobal", "T");
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    GlobalStopListenForNewMessages(); //stop listening for messages
}
public void EnableGlobalChat() //clicking button to enable global chat
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("DisableGlobal", "F");
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    GlobalListenForNewMessages(); //start listening for messages
}
```

Comment: I found a way around it by only starting the listener on Start, and instead blocked the messages in the Instantiation logic outside of this. In other words, the listener is never turned off, but the user won't see the messages as they won't be instantiated.